# Particles are black from one angle and normal from another

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm very new to Unity and I was just testing something, and I wanted to use the Unity particle system and wanted all particles to be the same color, but if you look at them from different angles, they are different color (black).

This is normal color:
[image: normal color]

And these are black particles:

[image: black color]

How do I fix that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of the lighting. if you look at the back of your red cubes you can see that they are black there. That's what is happening to your particles too. I think there is an option that removes the effects from light in the particle system settings. But it's simply because of the lighting. If you rotate the Directional Light Game Object the dark side will be on the other end.
I will try finding a fix right now.

[EDID] So I tried making this work, but it seems that if I go behind the particles I don't see black particle. I see nothing and I know that that is because I was using a sprite. I didn't have success recreating it but I looked at your pictures and I saw that your light is messed up and that may be a reason to your problem so here is how to fix the light mess up you have.

1.
[image]

You got Top left and go to "Window" then move your cursor to the "Rendering" section

2.
[image]

Then hover Over "Rendering" and click "Lighting"

3.
[image]

Finally a window "Lighting" should show up. Check that "Auto Generate" checkbox and your lighting will be okay. If its on and it's still messed up, jjust uncheck and check it.

[EDID 2] FOUND A FIX
So I have set up a material with a 2D sprite, and I just had to set the Shader of the material to "Particles/Standard Unlit" Here is how
1.

[image]ck.imgur.com/fgET4.png

Click on your Material you are using. Then go to the inspector and click where it says "Shader" the drop down menu and Choose "Particles"

2.
[image]

Then click "Standard Unlit" and you are done

Comment: I have tried turning off shadows and I can't find the option to remove light receiving.

Comment: @Yenz1 did it work out for you? Did you try the solution?